# How can i call the following void on a click button android?

Tags: java, android, call, void

I have the following code and i want to call this code onclick button
how can i do it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
String search = "stackoverflow";
String charset = "UTF-8";

URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

// Show title and URL of 1st result.
System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getTitle());
System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl());
```

}

Comment: From your questions its obvious you are new to android, I suggest you look at this tutorial as it will get you started: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

First you should change a few things. You shouldn't name the method `main`. In android you don't use a main method.  Also in android you don't use `System.out.println` but instead you use the Android `Log` class.

I would change the method to look like this:

```
public static void doSomething() throws Exception {
    String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
    String search = "stackoverflow";
    String charset = "UTF-8";

    URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset));
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
    GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

    // Show title and URL of 1st result.
    String tag = "myTag";
    Log.d(tag, results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getTitle());
    Log.d(tag, results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl());
}
```

Then when you define your `OnClickListener` simply invoke the above method in the `onClick()` method:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: sure it doesn't work by itself, you need to incorporate it into an Activity. See this: http://www.helloandroid.com/category/topics-covered/button

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the button that's getting clicked is called myButton. You'd then do:

```
myButton.addOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onCick(View view){
     String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
     String search = "stackoverflow";
     String charset = "UTF-8";

     URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset));
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
     GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);
   });
```

I took out the System.out.println because you can't really do those in android. You could try printing to the Log, making Toasts, or doing some other sort of output.